# How do I climb the roof after killing the Big Boo?

Tags: super-mario-64

In the original Super Mario 64, on the Big Boo's Balcony level, I've got up to the balcony, killed the fat boo, and I've been trying to get up on to that roof for the past 2 hours. So how do I get there?

Also, what's the best way to wall jump to get up to the top floor? I succeed there some times, but trying to get there feels more like playing the lottery than executing a jump for me.

Comment: So many hours wasted trying to get on this roof.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A quick glance at a few game guides shows they all seem to give the following approximate advice:

After killing the Big Boo check left and right and you should see small flat areas above the windows, long jump to them. From here either crawl up the slippery slope towards the centre of the roof or long jump over it (crawling is probably safer). Then follow the flat path here to the star.

Answer (score 9):

This YouTube video shows the way.  He takes shortcuts by sliding down parts of the roof, but it should be clear how you can do it without the sliding if that's too difficult (see DMA57361's answer if not).

Answer (score 1):

You can also jump off of the pillar-looking room that has the book case in it, instead of cartwheel jumping on the wall, which in my opinion is way more difficult.

This leads you to a door, up above, which then leads you to the 'attic' with the boo picture.

Go through the doors to lead to the roof.